# Need help on creating a generalized method for generating XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to write a generalized method for creating xml files using C#.

suppose my XML Skeleton is  like below

```
<root>
    <customer>
        <mobile></mobile>
        <email></email>
        <external></external>
        <firstname></firstname>
        <lastname></lastname>
        <gender></gender>
        <registered></registered>
        <custom>
            <field>
                <name></name>
                <value></value>
            </field>
            <field>
                <name></name>
                <value></value>
            </field>
        </custom>
    </customer>         
</root>
```

and if I will pass an object which contains all the required value, My method should return me an xml with values.

Please note:- My xml structure can change any time in future.

Currently I have created separate methods for crating different XML files.So whenever any changes happen in xml, I have to make changes in the method and deploy that again.

**EDIT :**

My customer class is like below

```
class Customer
    {       
        public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string county { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string companyname { get; set; }
        public string AddressOne { get; set; }
        public string AddressTwo { get; set; }
        public string AddressThree { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string RegisteredStore { get; set; }
        public string mailable { get; set; }
        public string rentable { get; set; }
        public string emailable { get; set; }
        public string JoinDate { get; set; }
        public string CustomerExternalID { get; set; }
        public string customergender { get; set; }
        public string dateofbirth { get; set; }
        public string homenumber { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }       

        //Custom Fields
        public string CurrencyRef { get; set; }
        public string InvitationStatus { get; set; }
        public string LastMailDate { get; set; }
        public string LastOrderDate { get; set; }
        public string NearestShop { get; set; }
        public string NearestShopDistance { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }       
        public string ShopperType { get; set; }
    }
```

Using XElement I am creating xml for a customer but when any new field is added in Custom Fields, I have to make changes in code to get the desired xml output.

Comment: We have no idea what your object looks like, or when properties should end up with their own element names vs the "custom" fields that you've mentioned - basically, this question lacks too many details for us to actually answer it at the moment.

Comment: What do you have so far? Show us which objects you are using for xml generation

Comment: Added more information.

Answer (score 0):

Turning an object into XML is called "Object Serialization" - the process of taking an in-memory object and turning it into XML that can be written to disk or sent over the network. Any object can be serialized (turned into XML or JSON).

Here's a link to a tutorial that shows how to do this in C#:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813